# What font used when I don't have that font

Tags: html, css, fonts

What font used when I don't have that font?

Example:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans+Narrow: 400' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <style>
      body {
        font: 400 30px/1.4 Arial;
      }

      p {
        font: 700 30px/1.4 "Pt Sans Narrow", Arial;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Example.</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

In this example, I don't have "Pt Sans Narrow 700". What font used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regular typeface of the PT Sans Narrow family used, with algorithmic (synthetic, fake) bolding applied to its glyphs. In this case, the result is clearly bolder than plain PT Sans Narrow but less bold that PT Sans Narrow Bold.

CSS Fonts Module Level 3 says, in its description of [`font-weight`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/#font-weight-prop): “Although the practice is not well-loved by typographers, bold faces are often synthesized by user agents for faces that lack actual bold faces. For the purposes of style matching, these faces must be treated as if they exist within the family. Authors can explicitly avoid this behavior by using the ‘font-synthesis’ property.” (The `font-synthesis` property is not supported yet.)

Unless there is some very special reason to ask for “fake bolding”, despite the existence of an actual bold typeface, you should specify bold (700) weight in the element where you refer to the the Google font, as instructed by the [Google documentation](https://www.google.com/fonts#UsePlace:use/Collection:PT+Sans+Narrow):

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans+Narrow:400,700'
   rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using google font that means it obviously take this font. But if you haven't used google font then if the client has no such font then it would take another font that is Arial.

Consider this example:

```
font-family: font1,font2,font3;
```

Here if the client browser has no such font `font1` then it will try to use `font2` and if `font2` is still not available then it will use `font3` but if `font3` is not still there the client's default font would be used there.

Answer (score 0):

Arial is used if Pt Sans Narrow is not present.

Answer (score 0):

When you open a HTML-File and the browser can't find the font, the normally it will use the default font of the browser.

Answer (score 0):

What will happen is it will look at the declared font stack you have made:

"Pt Sans Narrow", Arial;

and see the next font in the list after the one it cant find "Pt Sans Narrow".

In this case it will be Arial.

Answer (score 0):

This is highly depending on the rendering engine you are using.

Most engines make the font that is available "Pt Sans Narrow" just bold, which in turn would not look like the correct "Pt Sans Narrow" 700, but might come close.

And then there are those engines that skip an not available font and would choose the next in line, that might be Arial if it is available or the devices default font if the device also doesn't have Arial.